How to Use a Database with a Tizen 6.5 Web App Using Only HTML, CSS, and JavaScript?
I am developing a web app for Tizen 6.5 and am only using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. I need to implement database functionality to store and manage data within the app
Is it possible to use a database like MySQL or SQLite directly with just HTML, CSS, and JavaScript in a Tizen 6.5 web app? If not, what are the available alternatives for data storage in this context? Are there any client-side database solutions or APIs that I can use in a Tizen web app?
I'm looking for ways to handle data storage in my Tizen 6.5 app without relying on server-side technologies.

Hello, would you check this page? https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application/w3chtml5supplementary-features/storage/web-sql-database

Hasn't Web SQL already been deprecated? @LunchBasketball

There are several options described in the documentation
you can choose the best option for your purposes.
Described options are:

use a File
Indexed Database
Web Storage
Application caches
Web SQL

There are some examples how to utilise every approach for storing application data.

Instead of making a link-only answer, please take the time to summarize what the linked page says, because the page you linked-to won't be around forever.
